# Correct attribute for buttons in HTML

Tags: html, button, tags

What is better for empty buttons (without text) in HTML, attribute "aria-label" or "button"?
I use this empty tags and buttons for nodes in JS.

Has there been some discussion that it would be better for accessibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For empty buttons in HTML, it is best to use the `air-label` attribute.

This allows screen readers and accessibility devices to provide a description of the button for users with visual impairments. "aria-label" (`<button id="siteSearch" aria-label="Find in this site">Go</button>`)provides a textual description of the button, whereas using the `button` tag without text can cause confusion for users with disabilities.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role#basic_buttons

Please note, as pointed out in other posts ([Button with icon labelled with aria-label still an 'Empty Button' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820841/button-with-icon-labelled-with-aria-label-still-an-empty-button-error)) it is recommended not to put anything in a blank button but to leave the "standard view" like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
   <i class="fa fa-arrows">Sort</i>
</button>
```